# How to override browser default download behavior for files?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Lots of times we have to download files from the net. In IE we get to see the ugly download progress bar. In firefox we get to see a pop-up window opening etc.

However, I have never seen this being over ridden in any manner.

Until recently on the site

**> **thesixtyone** DOT com**

If we get to download a song free and click on the ok link to start the download we get a pop up to select location in the default style of windows. Then we see the progress bar as shown below.

**Any ideas on this? I am trying to see how these guys did this.**

you can see the image http://highwaves.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/61-download-bar.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think it is Flash. Cross-browser is Javascript to do not work

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want either an AJAX or Flash solution for this.

[AJAX* solution - provided by jQuery](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/)

*The asterisk here is because AJAX is not actually used, but does something similar in jQuery*

Unfortunately I don't have a handy link for a Flash solution at present...but there should be plenty of tutorials for something about writing a download manager in ActionScript :)